# output table in ACF that is in a repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm doing some displaying of tables and my table field is in a repeater field since i want to display 4 tables after each other that is a part of each other.

I'm looking at the code and see that it returns an array of 4.

I have looked at this code: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-table-field/#screenshots
But that only seem to work if the table is in a normal field and not inside a repeater field. I can't get any information out of it.

I have been trying to loop trough the repeater field and then run the code for the table, but that does not seem to work, all I get from the dump is `NULL`.

```
if( have_rows($table) ): // loop through the rows of data 
  while ( have_rows($table) ) : the_row();
    var_dump($table['information_table']) 
  endwhile; 
else : 
  // no rows found 
endif;
```

Anyone that has any tips on how i can get the tables to show from a repeater field?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code on what you tried already?

Comment: I used the code posted in the link, and i tried with: `if( have_rows($table) ):

  // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows($table) ) : the_row();

       var_dump($table['information_table'])

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;`

But i got NULL from the dump

Comment: Are you calling `get_sub_field()` at any point?

Comment: I have tried to do that too, but it does not seem to get any result.

Answer (score 0):

[repeater tables](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/template-repeater-field-with-table/)
The plugin author provides this code example: 
Not sure what you are missing. Try without the $table variable and use just the field name. Verify that you are using the correct sub_field name. Double check that you have the data saved in your database. It looks like you should be using sub_field('information_table') instead of $table['information_table']

```
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):

  // loop through the rows of data
  while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

    // get a sub field value (table field)
    $table = sub_field('sub_field_name');

    // use the “Output Table HTML” code with $table   

  endwhile;

else :

  // no rows found

endif;
```